# sphinx search return match and surrounding characters

Tags: mysql, sphinx

In Sphinx (using mysql connection), how can I match for a term and also get, let's say 5 characters before and after the match?

For example: a row contains `this is a word in a sentence`.

When I query: `SELECT term FROM table WHERE MATCH('"word*"')`

I would want to see `is a word in a s` returned. Is this possible?

**Edit** Using @barryhunter's helpful answer below, now trying to figure out how to fit this into my query:

`SELECT field1,field2,SPHINX_SNIPPETS(field3,indexName, "word") as snippet FROM tableName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats what `CALL SNIPPETS` is designed for. Although its counted in words, not charactors.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-call-snippets.html

```
CALL SNIPPETS('this is a word in a sentance','index1','word', 2 AS around, 5 as limit_words);
```

would get back

> ...  is a **word** in a ...

add `'' as chunk_separator` is dont want the ellipsis

---

Edit To add: then if want to build the snippet during the search query (not as a seperate CALL query), can use `SNIPPET()` function in the intial select
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-select

Comment: Thank you! Sounds perfect - I will take a look :)

Comment: would I need to use `SPHINX_SNIPPETS` for mysql? http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxse-snippets.html. I'm trying to do: `SELECT field1,field2,SPHINX_SNIPPETS(field3,indexName, "word") as snippet FROM tableName` but it throws a syntax error. BTW, I recognize your name from _every_ help article I've read so far :)

Comment: `SPHINX_SNIPPETS` is a **Mysql UDF**, its part of *SphinxSE* (a storage engine installed in MySQL directly!). But your initial example query is using **SphinxQL** - so yes, you want the SphinxQL `SNIPPET()` function! It can be used to build a snippet from a **String Attribute**